# How can I update the Database on a checkbox change in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I am trying to update my database when a checkbox is checked or unchecked. I want it to update when the checkbox is clicked. This is what I have so far, but my controller is never being hit. what can I do to fix it? Ideally I want to pass in the new value of customer.IsDone and customer.Id to my controller but I don't know how to do this.

Checkbox in my view

```
    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => customer.IsDone, new { onclick = "UpdateCustomer(IsDone)" })</td>
```

The function in my view

```
function UpdateCustomer(isDone) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: @Url.Action("UpdateCustomer", "Home"),
            data: { check: isDone },
            success: success,
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
```

this is my controller method

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateCustomer(bool check)
    {
        //code will be here to update the db

        var customers = new CustomerGetAll();
        var list = customers.Execute();

        return View("Customers", list);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see few issues in your code.

First of all, you are passing `IsDone` variable when calling the `UpdateCustomer` method. But where is `isDone` defined ?

Second, this line,

```
url: @Url.Action("UpdateCustomer", "Home"),
```

The `Url.Action` helper will output a string and your code will be like this when rendered in the browser

```
 url: /Home/UpdateCustomer,
```

Now the  browser's javascript framework usually thinks the second part after `:` as a js variable and if you have not defined it,it will throw a syntax error about using a not defined variable! But since we have  `\`, you will get another "Invalid regular expression flags" syntax error!

You should wrap the result in quotes to avoid this problem.

The below code should work

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m =>customer.IsDone, new { onclick = "UpdateCustomer(this)" })
```

and the script

```
function UpdateCustomer(elem) {
    var isDone = $(elem).is(':checked');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "@Url.Action("UpdateCustomer", "Home")",
        data: { check: isDone },
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

Also, If you want to update a specific customer record, you probably want to pass the customer Id as well when making the ajax call. You may keep that in html 5 data attribute on the checkbox markup and read that and use that as needed.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m =>customer.IsDone, new { onclick = "UpdateCustomer(this)",
                                                       data_customerid = customer.Id })
```

This will render the checkbox with html5 data attribute for "data-customerid". All you have to now do is, read this value and send it via ajax

```
function UpdateCustomer(elem) {
    var isDone = $(elem).is(':checked');
    var cid = $(elem).data('customerid');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("UpdateCustomer", "Home")',
        data: { check: isDone,customerId:cid },
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
}
```

Make sure your server action method has a new parameter to accept the customer id we are sending from client side code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateCustomer(bool check,int customerId)
{
   // to do  : Save and return something
}
```

Comment: It worked thanks! I had this before @Html.CheckBoxFor(m =>customer.IsDone, new { onclick = "UpdateCustomer(this)" }) but I am very new to this and I was not sure how else I could explain what I was trying to do. Is their any way I can pass the Id of the customer over to the controller as well?

Comment: See the updated answer which handles sending the customer id

Comment: Thanks! worked like a charm. I tried looking at another post similar to this one but it was to broad I could not get it.

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar, and I think you can solve your problem...

My HTML

```
<td>
   @{
      bool avalia1 = false;
      @Html.CheckBox("avalia1", avalia1, new { autocomplete = "off", data_on_text = "Sim", data_off_text = "Não" })
     }
</td>
```

JS

```
var avalia1 = $("#avalia1").is(":checked");

 var url = "/Telefonia/GravarAvaliacao";

$.ajax({

   url: url,
   datatype: "json",
   data: { 'avalia1': avalia1,'idgravacao': idgravacao },
   type: "POST",
   success: function (data) {
     }
 });
}
```

ON CONTROLLER

```
public JsonResult GravarAvaliacao(bool avalia1, string idgravacao)
    {
      string _userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
      var avaliaData = new OperadorAvaliacaoData();
      avaliaData.GravaAvaliacao(avalia1, idgravacao);

      return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The only diference is your model checkbox, and the action trigger.